# react video player carousel not showing videos

Tags: reactjs, youtube, video-player

I am using `react-elastic-carousel` and `reactjs-media` npm packages to display a carousel of youtube videos . However my videos do not show up and if I click on one I get `"Error appeared . Try again later "`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMmmN.png)

My code :

VideoSlider.js

```
import Carousel from "react-elastic-carousel";
import {YoutubePlayer} from 'reactjs-media';

export default function VideoSlider() {


  const links = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ng_bVJMm88',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zmx5D7dOYA&feature=emb_title',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKzXUTvn2es',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk97ev-M2Nw',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZta8t2L1pk',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOmSrKRWJS0',
  ]


  const breakPoints  = [
    { width: 1, itemsToShow: 1 },
    { width: 550, itemsToShow: 2, itemsToScroll: 2 },
    { width: 768, itemsToShow: 2 },
    { width: 1200, itemsToShow: 3 }
  ];


  return (
    <div className="bg-FQAItem  h-84 p-4">
        <div className="carousel-wrapper">
          <Carousel breakPoints={breakPoints} isRTL ={false} >
            {links.map((item,index) => (
                <YoutubePlayer  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zmx5D7dOYA&feature=emb_title"  height={350} key = {index}/>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
  )

}
```

I would appreciate your help with this .

Comment: Sometimes YouTube shows errors on playing videos if the file is stored locally, therefore I will recommend you to try once on the online editors like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic), [Codepen](https://www.codepen.io/pen), [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video link url is wrong.

Correct URL should be ->  https://youtu.be/5Zmx5D7dOYA

instead of

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zmx5D7dOYA&feature=emb_title

It is recommended that video links should be taken by **right-clicking on the video** instead of copying from the browser address bar.

Refer: SRC prop note here --> https://cranom.com/reactjs-media/api/youtube-player-props